# CFile & CStdioFile produces different results in writing & reading

Tags: file, visual-c++, mfc, cfile

To my understanding, when creating with typeBinary flag, CFile & CStdioFile should works indentically, except the latter is buffering the data so has a better performance.

So I write the following codes to confirm this:

```
ULONGLONG GetRand(ULONGLONG uMax)
{
    UINT uValue;

    if (rand_s(&uValue) == 0)
        return  (ULONGLONG)(((double)uValue / (double)UINT_MAX) * uMax);
    else
        return  0;
}

void CheckOffset(CFile& File1, CFile& File2)
{
    ULONGLONG uOffset1, uOffset2;
    CString strMsg;

    uOffset1 = File1.GetPosition();
    uOffset2 = File2.GetPosition();

    if (uOffset1 != uOffset2)
    {
        strMsg.Format(_T("Difference offset. Offset1 = %I64u. Offset2 = %I64u."), uOffset1, uOffset2);
        AfxMessageBox(strMsg);
    }
}

void CheckLength(CFile& File1, CFile& File2)
{
    ULONGLONG uLength1, uLength2;
    CString strMsg;

    uLength1 = File1.GetLength();
    uLength2 = File2.GetLength();

    if (uLength1 != uLength2)
    {
        strMsg.Format(_T("Difference length. Length1 = %I64u. Length2 = %I64u."), uLength1, uLength2);
        AfxMessageBox(strMsg);
    }
}

void CheckSeek(CFile& File1, CFile& File2, ULONGLONG uOffset)
{
    ULONGLONG uOffset1, uOffset2;
    CString strMsg;

    uOffset1 = File1.Seek(uOffset, CFile::begin);
    uOffset2 = File2.Seek(uOffset, CFile::begin);

    if (uOffset1 != uOffset2)
    {
        strMsg.Format(_T("Difference seek results. Offset1 = %I64u. Offset2 = %I64u."), uOffset1, uOffset2);
        AfxMessageBox(strMsg);
    }
}

void CheckRead(CFile& File1, CFile& File2, UINT uSize)
{
    BYTE lpBuf1[4096], lpBuf2[4096];
    UINT uRead1, uRead2;
    CString strMsg;

    //  Read buffer from file1 & file2
    uRead1 = File1.Read(lpBuf1, uSize);
    uRead2 = File2.Read(lpBuf2, uSize);

    if ((uRead1 != uRead2) || (memcmp(lpBuf1, lpBuf2, uRead1) != 0))
    {
        strMsg.Format(_T("Difference read results. uRead1 = %u. uRead2 = %u."), uRead1, uRead2);
        AfxMessageBox(strMsg);
    }
}

void CTestStdioFile64Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CFile File1;
    CStdioFile File2;
    UINT uSize;
    BYTE lpBuf[4096];
    CString strMsg;

    if (File1.Open(_T("F:\\Temp\\Test1.dat"), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeReadWrite | CFile::shareExclusive | CFile::typeBinary))
    {
        if (File2.Open(_T("F:\\Temp\\Test2.dat"), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeReadWrite | CFile::shareExclusive | CFile::typeBinary))
        {
            CheckOffset(File1, File2);
            CheckLength(File1, File2);

            //  Write data
            for (UINT uIndex = 0; uIndex < 20000; uIndex ++)
            {
                //  Generate a randome size for write
                uSize = (UINT)GetRand(4096);

                //  Generate buffer with random data
                for (UINT j = 0; j < uSize; j++)
                    lpBuf[j] = (BYTE)GetRand(255);

                //  Write buffer to file1 & file2
                File1.Write(lpBuf, uSize);
                File2.Write(lpBuf, uSize);

                File1.Flush();
                File2.Flush();

                CheckOffset(File1, File2);
                CheckLength(File1, File2);

                //  Seek to a randome location
                CheckSeek(File1, File2, GetRand(File1.GetLength()));

                //  Generate a randome size for read
                uSize = (UINT)GetRand(4096);

                CheckRead(File1, File2, uSize);
                CheckOffset(File1, File2);
            }

            File2.Close();
        }

        File1.Close();
    }
}
```

To my surprise, in the test process, there are many CFileException raised because CStdioFile::Write will write out less amount of data than expected.

Also there are many different read data reported.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your code in Debug mode, I am getting the following ASSERT.

> "Flush between consecutive read and write.",
>   !stream.has_any_of(_IOREAD)

The reason is following:

From C [Standard documentation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):
(Page 306, 7.21.5.3).

> When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third
>   character in the above list of mode argument values), both input and
>   output may be performed on the associated stream. However, output
>   shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to
>   the fflush function or to a file positioning function (fseek, fsetpos,
>   or rewind), and input shall not be directly followed by output without
>   an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input
>   operation encounters endof-file.

In your code, you are calling for `CheckRead` function at the end of the loop, but calling for `File1.Write` and `File2.Write` in the next iteration without calling for `fseek`/`flush`.

As a quick fix, you can add the following lines at the bottom of your CheckRead function:

```
File1.Seek(0, SEEK_CUR);
File2.Seek(0, SEEK_CUR);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the issue disappears. Also it seems I do not need to invoke File1.Flush & File2.Flush after writing since CheckSeek function will also work.